# Sorting Issue with User defined datatypes (Custom Properties) in C#

Tags: c#, linq, object, gridview-sorting, columnsorting

I have a grid where I am biding data from an object. Object has some complex data types. Below is my code  Able to sort ORDERID and OrderNumber BUT NOT CustomerInfo Property

Class :

```
public class Order
{    
    public Int32 OrderID{ get; set; }
    public String OrderNumber { get; set; }        
    public Customer CustomerInfo { get; set;}
}

public class Customer
{
    public Int64 CustomerNumber { get; set; }
    public String FirstName { get; set; }
    public String  LastName { get; set; }
    public String Phone { get; set; }
}
```

My Front End grid has columns defined one of the columns is

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Last Name"  ItemStyle-Width="15%" SortExpression="OrderCustomerInfo.LastName">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <%# Eval("OrderCustomerInfo.LastName") %>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

When I am passing Sort Expression : OrderCustomerInfo.LastName it's not recognizing the column  below is my sort function, I am getting error  --

Instance property 'OrderCustomerInfo.LastName' is not defined for type 'Order' 
  Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

> Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: Instance property
>   'OrderCustomerInfo.LastName' is not defined for type 'Order' )

Error Line --     Expression property = Expression.Property(param, columnName);     // x.ColumnName

```
public static IEnumerable<T> OrderBy<T>(this IEnumerable<T> collection, string columnName, SortDirection direction)
{
    ParameterExpression param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "x"); // x
    Expression property = Expression.Property(param, columnName);     // x.ColumnName
    Func<T, object> func = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, object>>(        // x => x.ColumnName
    Expression.Convert(Expression.Property(param, columnName),
    typeof(object)), param).Compile();

    Func<IEnumerable<T>, Func<T, object>, IEnumerable<T>> expression =
        SortExpressionBuilder<T>.CreateExpression(direction);
    IEnumerable<T> sorted = expression(collection, func);

    return sorted;
}
```

Comment: Should that be `OrderCustomerInfo.LastName` or `Order.CustomerInfo.LastName` ?

Comment: @Powerlord no I tried it already I am getting the same error -- Message: "Instance property 'Order.CustomerInfo.LastName' is not defined for type 'Order'"

Comment: Does your `OrderCustomerInfo` have `LastName` property?

Comment: @rageit, yes I do have and I am binding OrderCustomerInfo.LastName to the grid column

Answer (score 0):

Is the issue not that this line:

```
<%# Eval("OrderCustomerInfo.LastName") %>
```

Is missing a .?

```
<%# Eval("Order.CustomerInfo.LastName") %>
```

Comment: No,I am binding the object returned from data access which will use those classes... object name is OrderCustomerInfo and the property needs to be binded is LastName so it's OrderCustomerInfo.LastName

Comment: Does changing it to CustomerInfo.LastName work? It sounds to me as if OrderCustomerInfo is a List<Order>. I'm a work so I can't try this out, but I have a feeling your function will also need to be modified to work with complex objects. At a glance it doesn't look like it will handle nested properties

Comment: no it didn't work.... it works fine for regular properties but not for custom properties..

Answer (score 0):

The exception states that:

> Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: Instance property
>   'OrderCustomerInfo.LastName' is not defined for type 'Order' )

So I'd reckon you need to update your `SortExpression` and `Eval` as:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Last Name"  ItemStyle-Width="15%" SortExpression="CustomerInfo.LastName">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <%# Eval("CustomerInfo.LastName") %>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: I updated as mentioned in my previous commnets.... it didn't work .. May be I need to tweak the OrderBy fucntion to support complext types..